# Export: command not found

Tags: .profile, fortran

I have just upgraded my ubuntu.
After booting ubuntu 14.04 LTS I get this message:

```
/etc/profile :line 33 Export command not found.
```

This relates to the FORTRAN compiler.
Can anyone help me?
I attach the profile file.

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/composerxe/bin
Export PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/composerxe/include:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/tbb/include:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/intel/composerxe/man/en_US/man1
export MANPATH
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change line 33 from

```
Export PATH
```

to

```
export PATH
```